# C# dynamic design-time properties

Tags: c#, properties, design-time

I would like to have a control that allows a property to be shown if another property's value is set to a specific value. The following is a much simplified example of what I would like:

```
public class CustomButton : Control 
{
    private ButtonType _bType = ButtonType.OnOff;
    private Int32 _minPress = 50;   // 50 mS

    public ButtonType Button_Type
    {
        get { return _bType; }
        set { _bType = value; }
    }

    public Int32 Minimum_Press_Time // Only for momentary buttons
    {
        get { return _minPress; }
        set { _minPress = value; }
    }

}
public enum ButtonType 
{
    Momentary,
    OnOff
}
```

On adding CustomButton to a Windows.Forms form, the Minimum_Press_Time will only show in the Properties window if Button_Type is changed to ButtonType.Momentary.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: So then, at design time, how would you change the property to `Momentary` through the properties window? What if the user accidentally changed it and wants to change it back? Seems like a bad user experience, unless I'm missing something. Can you give a real-world scenario?

Comment: What I want "If the user places the button on a form and then sets Button_Type to Momentary, then the property Minimum_Press_Time appears in the Property window and can be set. If the user then sets Button_Type to OnOff the property Minimum_Press_Time is no longer displayed, although the value is still in the class variable." I don't think this possible. For my "real" class I have about 15 variables that change whether they are valid depending on the "type" chosen. It would appear my choices are to just have all the properties displayed (whether valid or not) or use multiple derived classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible to get close but it looks a little strange. I've done this on some controls before. Here is a full example of what you would need to do:

```
public partial class CustomButton : Control
{
    private ButtonType _buttonType = ButtonType.OnOff;
    private CustomButtonOptions _options = new OnOffButtonOptions();

    [RefreshProperties(System.ComponentModel.RefreshProperties.All)]
    public ButtonType ButtonType
    {
        get { return _buttonType; }
        set
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case DynamicPropertiesTest.ButtonType.Momentary:
                    _options = new MomentaryButtonOptions();
                    break;
                default:
                    _options = new OnOffButtonOptions();
                    break;
            }
            _buttonType = value;
        }
    }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public CustomButtonOptions ButtonOptions
    {
        get { return _options; }
        set { _options = value; }
    }

    public CustomButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public enum ButtonType
{
    Momentary,
    OnOff
}

public abstract class CustomButtonOptions
{

}

public class MomentaryButtonOptions : CustomButtonOptions
{
    public int Minimum_Press_Time { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Minimum_Press_Time.ToString();
    }
}

public class OnOffButtonOptions : CustomButtonOptions
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "No Options";
    }
}
```

So basically what is happening is you are using an ExpandableObjectConverter to convert an abstract type to a set of options. You then use the RefreshProperties attribute to tell the property grid that it will need to refresh the properties after this property changes.

This is the easiest way I've found to come as close to what you are asking for as possible. The property grid doesn't always refresh the right way so sometimes there will be a "+" sign next to an options set with no expandable properties. Use the "ToString" in the properties to make the display on the property grid look intelligent.

Comment: I tried this, and it is not "exactly" what I wanted, but it does provide what I need, so I am marking this as my accepted answer... Thanks

Comment: Without diving into trying to make types that are compiled dynamically, this is about the best you can hope for. WPF handles it a lot better than WinForms.